# Best practice for storing a polymorphic belongsTo relation

Tags: laravel

We have a need for multiple models to share a documents relation. Due to that, I've used a polymorphic one to many as per the below schema.

```sql
Schema::create('client', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
});
```

```sql
Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('type_id')->constrained('document_types');
    $table->string('path'),
    $table->morphTo('documentable');
});
```

**Documents Model**

```php
public function documentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

**Client Model**

```php
public function documents()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Document::class, 'documentable');
}
```

Each document will need to relate to a specific type. For example, one document might relate to the customers signed agreement and another may relate to a completely different document - These types will need to be 'query-able'.

What's the best way to proceed with this? As far as I'm aware, my options are;

1. Create a `document_types` table and set a `belongsTo` relation on the documents table.
2. Create an enum column on the documents table.

A side note on this. This will be consumed via an API. There will be the following resources:

```php
Route::apiResource('client', 'ClientController');
Route::apiResource('client.documents', 'ClientDocumentController');
```

With whichever solution is proposed above, how would you propose the API handles the document type when creating/updating a document?

1. If the use of a `documents_type` table, would the end-user have to hit a resource for the document type, to obtain the document type ID prior to creating/updating a document?
2. If the use of enums, would the API just expect a string for the given document type?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first part, the idea of morphing already solves issue 1, so do not create a `document_types` as you will already store the type in `documentable_type` (that would be the document itself, the correct type). and about `enums`, I do not recommend DB enums at all, as then altering the table to change this enums is a hell itself with Laravel (I am not sure if it got fixed in recent versions), so avoid DB enums 100%. Related to API URL, the only thing I can think of is to have a URL like `/api/document/{type}/{id}`, where `type = documentable_type` and `id = documentable_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason for the document_types table is that each model can have many different types of documents. So because client has a document relation, it might contain one document type of X and another of Y. This also means the api can’t rely on just a model and an id.

Comment: And what is the problem with having a `documentable_type = Y` with the corresponding ID and a `documentable_type = X` with the corresponding ID ? You should have a `agree_documents`, `letter_documents`, `X_documents` and `Y_documents` table, it will relate automatically to these models/tables depending on the `documentable_type`, hence you can have any you want.

Comment: Because in this instance, every time I need to create some sort of document type/group, I'd need to create a new model. If there's 50 document types, I've got 50 tables? My aim is to have one documents table with a documentable_type and documentable_id for multiple models, but those models each have many document types, which the document needs to relate to. Sorry if I've not explained myself correctly.

Comment: Well... If you have 50 document types, you should have 50 models (and 50 tables), because each document is an entity, each document differs from other, else it would be same document... I used to work with some stuff like "configuration" and I had a single model but I always must knew which type of config I was using, that was a really shitty experience as you cannot rely on the model itself to tell you what you have, but you have to ask the model what type it is and it is really a pain in the ass... but it depends on your project. So there is no a clear answer. I would need more info.